# How to disable end date picker until user enters the start date?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Below is the code I use currently. It allows the user to select the end date before selecting the start date.

Is it possible to disable the end date picker until the user enters the start date?

```
var today = new Date();
var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);
$( "#conference_start_date" ).datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "/roswellpark/images/calendar_icon.png",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonText: '',
    yearRange: "-100y",
    changeYear: true,
    changeMonth:true,
    minDate: tomorrow,
    onSelect: function (date) {
        var selectedDate = new Date(date);
        var msecs = 86400000*3; // one day have 86400000 micro seconds
        var defaultSelectedDate = new Date(selectedDate.getTime() + msecs);
        var endDate =  new Date(selectedDate.getTime()+86400000);
        $("#conference_end_date").datepicker('option', 'minDate', endDate);
        $('#conference_end_date').datepicker("setDate", defaultSelectedDate);
    }
});
$("#conference_start_date").focus(function() {
    $("#conference_start_date").datepicker("show");
    $("#ui-datepicker-div").css("width", "16em");
}); 

$( "#conference_end_date" ).datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "/roswellpark/images/calendar_icon.png",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonText: '',
    yearRange: "-100y",
    changeYear: true,
    changeMonth:true
});
$("#conference_end_date").focus(function() {
    $("#conference_end_date").datepicker("show");
    $("#ui-datepicker-div").css("width", "16em");
});
```

Comment: add ur cide ub js fiddle please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this..**

```
$(document).ready(fuction(){
$("#conference_end_date").attr("disabled", "disable");// add end date to disable

});

$( "#conference_start_date" ).datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "/roswellpark/images/calendar_icon.png",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonText: '',
    yearRange: "-100y",
    changeYear: true,
    changeMonth:true,
    minDate: tomorrow,
    onSelect: function (date) {

$("#conference_end_date").removeAttr("disabled");// remove disable after select startdate

        var selectedDate = new Date(date);
        var msecs = 86400000*3; // one day have 86400000 micro seconds
        var defaultSelectedDate = new Date(selectedDate.getTime() + msecs);
        var endDate =  new Date(selectedDate.getTime()+86400000);
        $("#conference_end_date").datepicker('option', 'minDate', endDate);
        $('#conference_end_date').datepicker("setDate", defaultSelectedDate);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make the *end date* field disabled and unconfigured until the user provides the *start date* value. Then, in a callback function (this is most likely the `onSelect`) you could configure the datepicker using the `datepicker` function, and make the button enabled.